# Archive the Images after conversion of Image to string in python

Tags: python, image, text, ocr, archive

I am doing **Tesseract-OCR** for Image **('test.jpg')**. After ran the below code (OCR) part i am saving the Extracted string into **"OUTPUT.txt"**. 
Now i want to Archive the Image **("test.jpg")** can you please help me?

```
file='test.jpg'
def ocr(file):
    foo = Image.open(file)
    print(foo.size)
    foo = foo.resize((2000,3000),Image.ANTIALIAS)
    pytes=pytesseract.image_to_string(foo)
    with open("OUTPUT.txt","w") as file:
            file.write(str(pytes))
    print(pytes)

ocr(file)
```

Comment: What do you mean by archiving file?

Comment: I want to create one folder called "Archive" i want to put "test.jpg" into that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
import os
from shutil import copyfile

archive_path = "path to your archive folder"
if not os.path.exists(archive_path):
    os.makedirs(arichive_path)

copyfile("test.jpg", archive_path)
```

Comment: Thanks a lot mohammad:-) it is working fine when i give direct image file for example "D\\python\\test1.jpg" but i want to put seperate folder itself like "D\\python\\ this

Comment: You mean your images are on different folders?

Comment: instead of test.jpg in code you should give the path of your image